# How to zero out rows and columns in a SymPy Matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I'm implementing a simple FEA code and I need to zero out particular rows and columns to apply boundary conditions. Example matrix:

[image: Example matrix here]

I tried with `my_matrix[:,1] = 0` but it returns an error: `ValueError: unexpected value: 0`

Can some one guide me on how to make columns and rows zero?

Comment: Please share a complete minimum example code that generates `my_matrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy matrix objects don't appear to support assigning a constant to multiple entries like numpy array objects.

Try `my_matrix[:,1] = [0]*my_matrix.shape[0]` instead, which generates a list of `0`s of length equal to the number of rows of `my_matrix`.